# TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, pandas, api, post

Python Pandas Dataframe to API

I have a python pandas data frame where a large number of rows ( > 1M) are processed in the aspect of formatting and merging of columns. The script works great. However, I need to be able to take the results of this data processing and POST through an API to my server.

Originally the script wrote to a `.csv` file, but now I am trying to push the data through an API. The following is the API portion of the POST code:

```
dataPush = {
    'firstName': data['P_First_Name'],
    'lastName': data['P_Last_Name'],
    'dateOfBirth': data['DATE_OF_BIRTH'],
    'addressStreet': data['Street'],
    'addressCity': data['RESIDENTIAL_CITY'],
    'addressState': data['RESIDENTIAL_STATE'],
    'addressPostalCode': data['RESIDENTIAL_ZIP'],
}

client.request('POST', 'PersonOfInterest', dataPush)
```

The above code results in: `TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing that way you are setting the attribute **'firstName'** the entire column (Series).

```
'firstName': data['P_First_Name'],
```

you need to iterate over the rows, something similar to it:

```
for row in data.iterrows():
   'firstName': row['P_First_Name']
```

Comment: thank you!! I have now breached another issue: error, ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='3.239.26.101', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/PersonOfInterest (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9b7e3f7a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out')) is this a result if a failure of my server or something I am not understanding

Comment: If you mark your original question answered, it helps me to collect some reputation. About your other problem, break the calls in smaller ones. All at once, you can face all types of issues...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but when using `json.dump(dictionary,file,indent = x)` method of the json library.

One way to solve this is converting the DataFrame individual series to lists for each value entry of the key:value pair in your dictionary, it would be:

```
dataPush = {
    'firstName': data['P_First_Name'].to_list(),
    'lastName': data['P_Last_Name'].to_list(),
    ...
}

client.request('POST', 'PersonOfInterest', dataPush)
```

as it finds lists to be "JSON serializable" (at least with when using the `json.dump()` method).
I am not sure but it could be less computing demanding than `iterrows()` method.